# how to upgrade Xcache via Ondrej ppa

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, ppa

I use Ubuntu 12.04 for my VPS.
I have Xcache installed.
Xcache version is 1.3
Current Xcache version is 3.1
Xcache 3.1 is not available on ubuntu 12.04 officially

I found backport https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/php5/+sourcepub/3606697/+listing-archive-extra for version 3.1

How on earth do I upgrade Xcache 1.3 to Xcache 3.1?

I would really appreciate solutution

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use the entire [Ondřej Surý PHP5 PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/php5/) by adding it as a repository source on your server. Instructions (and the packages it's going to upgrade — **note that this will include PHP**) are right there on the page but using it is simple enough:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

If you have production sites, you should first test them with the stack being offered in this PPA (newer apache 2.4, php, libmemcached, etc). I've given you just enough information to be completely deadly.

If you don't backup or test beforehand, you're not doing it right.

---

Or you can try just downloading the [XCache package from the PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/php5/+sourcepub/3606697/+listing-archive-extra) (click the architecture you need) and `dpkg -i <filename>`... But be aware that that version of XCache may well be incompatible with ancient versions of PHP. You might need the full PHP stack offered here.

Comment: thanks, I chose to install package only as I don't want to break php or any other package that virtualmin is relied upon. When I do dpk - i xcache 3.1 from ondrej repository I get the following error: php5-xcache depends on phpapi-20121212; where do I get it?

Comment: As I was saying, the newer version if xcache might rely on newer PHP features. I'm not sure you have much of a choice here.